# Get details of event from System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntry

Tags: powershell, event-log

I'm writing a PowerShell script to keep an eye on some event log entries. I'm able to subscribe to the Security log and trigger a script block when one of the events is logged. However, I can't find how to get the relevant data from the event object. The event object I am interacting with is of type `System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntry`. I checked the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlogentry?view=netframework-4.8) of that class and wrote all of the available properties to the console with a script block:

```
$CredentialGuardEventIds = 5379,5381,5382
$SecurityLog = Get-EventLog -List | Where-Object {$_.Log -eq 'Security'}

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $SecurityLog -SourceIdentifier NewCredentialEvent -EventName EntryWritten -Action {
    $entry = $event.SourceEventArgs.Entry
    if ($CredentialGuardEventIds -contains $entry.EventID) {
        Write-Host "Event $($entry.EventID) occured"
        Write-Host "CanRaiseEvents: $($entry.CanRaiseEvents)"
        Write-Host "Category: $($entry.Category)"
        Write-Host "CategoryNumber: $($entry.CategoryNumber)"
        Write-Host "Container: $($entry.Container)"
        Write-Host "Data: $($entry.Data)"
        Write-Host "DesignMode: $($entry.DesignMode)"
        Write-Host "EntryType: $($entry.EntryType)"
        Write-Host "EventID: $($entry.EventID)"
        Write-Host "Events: $($entry.Events)"
        Write-Host "Index: $($entry.Index)"
        Write-Host "InstanceId: $($entry.InstanceId)"
        Write-Host "MachineName: $($entry.MachineName)"
        Write-Host "Message: $($entry.Message)"
        Write-Host "ReplacementStrings: $($entry.ReplacementStrings)"
        Write-Host "Site: $($entry.Site)"
        Write-Host "Source: $($entry.Source)"
        Write-Host "TimeGenerated: $($entry.TimeGenerated)"
        Write-Host "TimeWritten: $($entry.TimeWritten)"
        Write-Host "UserName: $($entry.UserName)"
    }
}
```

Which outputs the following data:

```
CanRaiseEvents:
Category: (13824)
CategoryNumber: 13824
Container:
Data:
DesignMode:
EntryType: SuccessAudit
EventID: 5381
Events:
Index: 771286
InstanceId: 5381
MachineName: REDACTED
Message: Vault credentials were read.

Subject:
        Security ID:            S-1-5-26-2325928431-9938217593-9384716351-3004
        Account Name:           redacted
        Account Domain:         REDACTED
        Logon ID:               0x44d9f

This event occurs when a user enumerates stored vault credentials.
ReplacementStrings: S-1-5-21-2356930457-929305828-1234252251-1534 redacted REDACTED 0x3459f 142 6 2019-09-20T23:33:31.671135000Z 15136
Site:
Source: Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing
TimeGenerated: 09/24/2019 21:26:27
TimeWritten: 09/24/2019 21:26:27
UserName:
```

However, the data I am interested in appears in the "Details" tab of the event viewer:

[image]

How can I access the data in the Details pane from a `System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntry` object?

### Note

The events in question were added in a recent release of Windows 10 (I believe 1903), and are related to Windows Defender Credential Guard. I can't find much documentation for them, but a good video on why they were added can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1JJAob5fkWs&t=736s

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, that the information is in the message property, but I don't have the events that you are looking for.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't the same for the events I am working with, so it can't be assumed to be the same for all events. Thanks for taking a look though.

Answer (score 0):

Although I dont have events with those ID's, the following demo code should get you the idea.
Using `Get-WinEvent` you can get the XML data like this:

```
$result = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName="Security";Id=4624} -MaxEvents 100 | ForEach-Object {
    # convert the event to XML and grab the Event node
    $eventXml = ([xml]$_.ToXml()).Event

    # get the 'TargetDomainName' value and check it does not start with 'NT AUTHORITY'
    $domain = $eventXml.EventData.Data[$dataItems['TargetDomainName']].'#text'
    if ($domain -ne 'NT AUTHORITY' ) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Domain    = $domain
            UserName  = $eventXml.EventData.Data[$dataItems['TargetUserName']].'#text'
            UserSID   = $eventXml.EventData.Data[$dataItems['TargetUserSid']].'#text'
            LogonType = $logonTypes[[int]$eventXml.EventData.Data[$dataItems['LogonType']].'#text'] 
            Date      = [DateTime]$eventXml.System.TimeCreated.SystemTime
            Computer  = $eventXml.System.Computer
        }
    }
}

$result | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Get-EventLog provides you the event log message for the event.
The data you are trying to extract is part of the event manifest, and not presented in the log message.
In order to get this data, use "Get-WinEvent".

```
$result = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName="Security";Id=5381} -MaxEvents 100 | ForEach-Object {
    # convert the event to XML and extract properties
    $eventXml = ([xml]$_.ToXml()).Event
    $domain = $eventXml.EventData.Data[$dataItems['CountOfCredentialsReturned']].'#text'
}

$result | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Comment: This is promising, but it doesn't address my main concern which pushed me towards `Register-ObjectEvent`: how can I reliably get the process name and path from this? Unless I am missing something, the details only return the process ID. If I were to run this on an interval, even as frequently as 5 seconds, I might not be able to look up the process name and path from the ID before the process exits.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27211427/find-process-name-by-its-process-id

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the part I'm having an issue with. I'm more concerned with short-lived processes. For example, if Mimicatz is executed and grabs all of the credentials from CredMan, it will exit in just a couple of seconds. If my script runs 5 seconds later and looks at the events, the process ID in the event will be useless, since there is no longer a process with that ID to look up. Maybe I can match the event 5381 to a corresponding event 4688?